# Як відрізнити кореляцію від прикладки?

Tags: граматика, синтаксис

Що таке кореляція? Як визначити у словосполученні «дівчина-красуня» частина «красуня» - прикладка чи це словосполучення з кореляцією? Чи і те, і інше?
За [підручником Загнітко "Синтаксис"](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/128794/Books_2010_2019_018-2013-1_4.pdf?sequence=1), дівчина-агроном - кореляція, але чому не прикладка?

Comment: якщо вам підходить відповідь, можете "прийняти" її - клавіша під стрілочками голосування за чи проти відповіді на питання. до того ж, я зараз вам відредаґую питання, а ви подивіться, як це робиться. вітаю на сайті, сподіваюсь, вам тут буде затишно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Це не взаємовиключні речі.

[Прикладка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0) — це те, яку роль слово виконує **в реченні** (зазвичай прикладку розглядають як різновид [означення](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE))).

Кореляція (в одному із значень цього слова) — це підвид зв'язку **в словосполученні**; умовно вважаймо, що це те, яку роль слово відіграє в словосполученні.